# Jquery onclick link load url

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

**I can´t get works this with jquery:**

```
<a href="#" onclick='jQuery('#load_url').show(1000).load('http://google.es');'>Google</a>
```

I need when i do click over this link load the url inside div called #load_url

All time happend the same thing and no load never the url if i test this with one function works but i need works inside link and at the moment i try all kind of things and never get works fine

Comment: What is `#load_url`?

Comment: <div id="load_url"></div> , div inside i need load url

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle example?

Comment: won't the same origin policy stop you doing this? Don't you need to use something like an iframe?

Comment: yes, as previous comment mentioned, you cannot load from external domain

Comment: Only i want load url from link and i don´t know how put right

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is the cross-origin policy. I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ak95xw74/), it logs the error to the browser console: `Cross-Origin request blocked`. Any you can't solve this using `iframe` either, as Google blocks external framing request:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: 
https://www.google.es/?gws_rd=ssl does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

Comment: Google it´s only example can be other url the most important it´s if i writte ok this expresion with the link

Comment: Well, most sites disallow cross-origin requests, if the target is your own site (or any other site, where you may change the policy), its okay, otherwise this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If this is only for testing purposes, you can use this:

```js
function myFunc() {
    
    $.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/dev/get?url=google.es&callback=?', function(data){
 $('#load_url').show(1000).html(data.contents);
});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='load_url'></div>

<a href="#" onclick="myFunc()">Google</a>
```

This uses http://anyorigin.com/ to bypass the Same Origin Policy restriction.

So for using it a few times, this would work, but as it says on the website, too much use can cause you to be banned.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) for ways to bypass the policy.

If in the real application, you link to a page on your site, you can simply use what you were using before:

```
<a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#load_url').show(1000).load('localpage.html');">local page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntaxically your tag is incorrect, your break the main string ; replace the outer quotes by double quotes, and use a local page (create a test.html page in the same directory for example, and try to load this one instead of an external website) :

```
<a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#load_url').show(1000).load('test.html');">Google</a>
```